# Organiser Refills/Inlays using LaTeX

Tags: scripts, calendar, organisation

Every year I need to refill my beloved organiser. But the refills on simple A5 paper are sold for incredible prices around $20.

> Is there a way to create organiser inlays using LaTeX (e.g. one week on two A5 pages)?

Comment: If you could make the question more specific, you might invite other users to suggest different solutions. As in, "This is what I came up with, how specifically could I make it better?"

Comment: Perhaps the original creator of the refills/inlays has some copyright on it (as they sell them for about $20?) Did you take that into account?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Yes but I don't think the solution lower on the page is notably enough to come close to something worth to copyright -- its just a simple text arrangement.

Comment: @smoneck: I don't know the originals ;-)

Answer (score 8):

It's your lucky day, man!

[image: calendar]

Check this out:

```
\documentclass[%
    BCOR=2cm,%  Space for hole puncher
    DIV=25,%    Size of textbody
    12pt%       Fontsize
]{scrbook}
%
%%%%%%%%%% PACKAGES %%%%%%%%%%
%
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,multirow}
%
%%%%%%%%%% COUNTER %%%%%%%%%%
%
\newcount\counter
\newcount\startdate
\newcount\starttime
\newcount\stoptime
\newcount\sundaybegin
\newcount\week
%
%%%%%%%%%% CUSTOMISATIONS %%%%%%%%%%
%
%% Month
\renewcommand{\month}{January}
%% Date to start the week with
\startdate=11
%% Morning starttime
\starttime=8
%% Evening time
\stoptime=21
%% Starttime sunday
% Min \starttime+1
% Max \stoptime-2
\sundaybegin=14
%% Weeknumber
\week=1
%% Rule width thick
\newcommand{\rulew}{.15em}
%% Extra space
%\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}
%
%%%%%%%%%% DEFINITIONS %%%%%%%%%%
%
\newcommand{\lendt}{\cmidrule[\rulew](l){1-2}\cmidrule[\rulew](l){3-4}\cmidrule[\rulew](l){5-6}}
\newcommand{\lend}{\cmidrule(l){1-2}\cmidrule(l){3-4}\cmidrule(l){5-6}}
\newcommand{\lsun}{\cmidrule(l){1-2}\cmidrule(l){3-4}}
\newcommand{\lsunt}{\cmidrule(l){1-2}\cmidrule(l){3-4}\cmidrule[\rulew](l){5-6}}
\newcommand{\printday}[2]{{\LARGE \textbf{#1}}\,\, \large \textbf{#2}}
\newcommand{\neutralline}{& & & & &}
\newcommand{\footer}{\centering\rule{7cm}{\cmidrulewidth} \raisebox{-0.5ex}{\LaTeX{}} \rule{7cm}{\cmidrulewidth}}
\newcommand{\printmonth}{{\LARGE \textbf{\month}}}
%
%%%%%%%%%% TABLE CONTENT LEFT SIDE %%%%%%%%%%
%
% Correction due to \global\advance
\advance\startdate-6
%
\advance\stoptime1
\long\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}
%
\def\tabledataleft{} \counter=\the\starttime
\loop
    \edef\tabline{\the\counter &  & \the\counter & & \the\counter & }
    \expandafter\addto\expandafter\tabledataleft\expandafter{\neutralline \\\lend}
    \expandafter\addto\expandafter\tabledataleft\expandafter{\tabline \\\lend}
    \advance \counter 1
    \ifnum \counter<\the\stoptime
\repeat 
%
%%%%%%%%%% TABLE CONTENT RIGHT SIDE %%%%%%%%%%
%
\def\tabledatarightupper{} \counter=\the\starttime
\loop
    \edef\tabline{\the\counter &  & \the\counter & & & }
    \expandafter\addto\expandafter\tabledatarightupper\expandafter{\neutralline \\\lend}
    \expandafter\addto\expandafter\tabledatarightupper\expandafter{\tabline \\\lend}
    \advance \counter 1
    \ifnum \counter<\the\sundaybegin
\repeat 
%
\advance\sundaybegin1
\def\tabledatarightinter{} \counter=\the\sundaybegin
\newcount\sundaystop
\sundaystop=\the\sundaybegin
\advance\sundaystop1
\loop
    \edef\tabline{\the\counter &  & \the\counter & & & }
    \expandafter\addto\expandafter\tabledatarightinter\expandafter{\neutralline \\\lsun}
    \expandafter\addto\expandafter\tabledatarightinter\expandafter{\tabline \\\lsun}
    \advance \counter 1
    \ifnum \counter<\the\sundaystop
\repeat 
\advance\sundaybegin-1
\advance\sundaystop1
%
\def\tabledatarightlower{} \counter=\the\sundaystop
\loop
    \edef\tabline{\the\counter &  & \the\counter & & & }
    \expandafter\addto\expandafter\tabledatarightlower\expandafter{\neutralline \\\lend}
    \expandafter\addto\expandafter\tabledatarightlower\expandafter{\tabline \\\lend}
    \advance \counter 1
    \ifnum \counter<\the\stoptime
\repeat 
\advance\sundaystop-1
%
\begin{document}
%
%% Empty page to start left
\thispagestyle{empty}
\mbox{}
\clearpage
%
\pagestyle{empty}
\enlargethispage{1cm}
%
%%%%%%%%%% LEFT TABLE %%%%%%%%%%
%
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lXlXlX}
    \multicolumn{6}{l}{\printmonth \hfill Week \the\week}\\[.2em]\midrule[\rulew]
    \addlinespace[.5em]
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\printday{\the\startdate}{Monday}} \global\advance\startdate 1\relax &%
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\printday{\the\startdate}{Tuesday}} \global\advance\startdate 1\relax &%
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\printday{\the\startdate}{Wednesday}}\global\advance\startdate 1\relax \\[2cm]
     & & & & & \\\lendt
    \tabledataleft
     & & & & & \\\lendt
\end{tabularx}
%
\vfill
\footer
%
\clearpage
\enlargethispage{1cm}
% Correction due to \global\advance
\advance\startdate-6
%
%%%%%%%%%% RIGHT TABLE %%%%%%%%%%
%
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lXlXlX}
    \multicolumn{6}{l}{Week \the\week \hfill \printmonth}\\[.2em]\midrule[\rulew]
    \addlinespace[.5em]
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\printday{\the\startdate}{Thursday}} \global\advance\startdate 1\relax &%
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\printday{\the\startdate}{Friday}}   \global\advance\startdate 1\relax &%
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\printday{\the\startdate}{Saturday}} \global\advance\startdate 1\relax \\[2cm]
    & & & & & \\\lendt
    \tabledatarightupper
    & & & & & \\\lsunt
    \addlinespace[-.15em]
    \the\sundaybegin & & \the\sundaybegin & & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\multirow{4}{*}[1.5em]{\printday{\the\startdate}{Sunday}}}\\\lsun
    \tabledatarightinter
    & & & & & \\\lsun
    \the\sundaystop & & \the\sundaystop & & & \\\lsunt
    \tabledatarightlower
    & & & & & \\\lendt
\end{tabularx}
%
\vfill
\footer
\end{document}
```

You just need to give it the

- Name of the month
- Date of monday
- Number of the week

and it gives you a nice week to refill! Now it's easy to write a script that runs through 52 weeks.

Furthermore, señoras y señores, you can customise it to your needs by using:

- Starttime (here: *8*)
- Endtime (here: *21*)
- Height of the sunday -- more/less Saturday/Sunday (here: *14*)
- Width of the thick rules (here: *.15em*)
- Row height

Another **Example** using:

- Starttime: *5*
- Endtime: *20*
- Height of the sunday: *8*

[image: calendar2]

If you don't have A5 paper, <s>print two on A4 and</s> cut it -- printing two pages on one is a mess (needed page sequence: {2,3}, {4,1}, {6,7}, {8,5}, ...). The holes of special arrangements can be done easily as shown [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OdBN6iltLh0).

Cheers!

---

**EDIT**

I changed some setting, added a month turnover (eg. 31-->1) and put a <s>`python2`</s> `python3` wrapper around it. <s>Code is certainly not as elegant as possible but works like a charm.</s> (EDIT 2)

```
import calendar

########## CUSTOMIZATIONS ##########

## Year
year=2021

# Labels
months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
#months = [calendar.LocaleTextCalendar().formatmonthname(year,i,1).split(' ')[0] for i in range(1,13)]

labels = {
    'label_week':       'Week',
    'label_monday':     'Monday',
    'label_tuesday':    'Tuesday',
    'label_wednesday':  'Wednesday',
    'label_thursday':   'Thursday',
    'label_friday':     'Friday',
    'label_saturday':   'Saturday',
    'label_sunday':     'Sunday',
}

## Morning starttime
starttime="8"

## Evening time
stoptime="21"

## Starttime sunday
# Min \starttime+1
# Max \stoptime-2

sundaybegin="14"

## Rule width thick
thickrulewidth="2pt"

## Midrule width
midrulewidth="1pt"

## Thinrule width
thinrulewidth=".5pt"

## Extra space
extrarowheight="1pt"

#
####################################
#

days = {
    0: 'pymond',
    1: 'pytue',
    2: 'pywed',
    3: 'pythur',
    4: 'pyfr',
    5: 'pysat',
    6: 'pysun'
}

#Collect all mondays in a list
mondays = []

for month in range( 1, 13 ):

   for week in calendar.monthcalendar(year,month):

      if not week[0] == 0:
         mondays.append( [week[0], 0] )

# If year doesn't end with a friday, append January to months
if calendar.monthcalendar(year, 12)[-1][-1] == 0:
    months.append( months[0] )

Nweeks = len(mondays)

# Add length of corresponding month to each monday
month = 1
for week in range( Nweeks ):

   Ndaysinmonth = calendar.monthrange( year, month )[1]

   # First week
   if week == 0:
      mondays[week][1] = Ndaysinmonth

   # Increasing day in month => same month
   elif mondays[week][0] > mondays[week-1][0]:
      mondays[week][1] = Ndaysinmonth

   # Next month
   else:
      mondays[week][1] = calendar.monthrange( year, month+1 )[1]
      month+=1

head = r'''
   \documentclass[%
      BCOR=2cm,%  Space for hole puncher
      DIV=30,%   Size of textbody
      paper=a4,%  A4 paper
      fontsize=12pt%    Fontsize
   ]{scrbook}
   %
   %%%%%%%%%% PACKAGES %%%%%%%%%%
   %
   \usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,multirow}
   %\usepackage{pgfpages}
   %\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[odd numbered pages right,a4paper,landscape,border shrink=0mm]
   %%%%%%%%%% COUNTER %%%%%%%%%%
   %
   \newcount\counter
   \newcount\startdate
   \newcount\starttime
   \newcount\stoptime
   \newcount\sundaybegin
   \newcount\week
   \newcount\datemonday
   \newcount\datetuesday
   \newcount\datewednesday
   \newcount\datethursday
   \newcount\datefriday
   \newcount\datesaturday
   \newcount\datesunday
   %
   %%%%%%%%%% CUSTOMISATIONS %%%%%%%%%%
   %
   %% Morning starttime
   \starttime=pystarttime
   %% Evening time
   \stoptime=pystoptime
   %% Starttime sunday
   % Min \starttime+1
   % Max \stoptime-2
   \sundaybegin=pysundaybegin
   %% Rule width thick
   \newcommand{\rulew}{pyrulewidth}
   %% Midrule width
   \newcommand{\mrulew}{pymidrulewidth}
   %% thinrule width
   \newcommand{\trulew}{pythinrulewidth}
   %% Extra space
   \setlength{\extrarowheight}{pyextrarowheight}
   %
   %%%%%%%%%% DEFINITIONS %%%%%%%%%%
   %
   \newcommand{\lendt}{\cmidrule[\rulew](l){1-2}\cmidrule[\rulew](l){3-4}\cmidrule[\rulew](l){5-6}}
   \newcommand{\lend}[1]{\cmidrule[#1](l){1-2}\cmidrule[#1](l){3-4}\cmidrule[#1](l){5-6}}
   \newcommand{\lsun}[1]{\cmidrule[#1](l){1-2}\cmidrule[#1](l){3-4}}
   \newcommand{\lsunt}[1]{\cmidrule[#1](l){1-2}\cmidrule[#1](l){3-4}\cmidrule[\rulew](l){5-6}}
   \newcommand{\printday}[2]{{\LARGE \textbf{#1}}\,\, \large \textbf{#2}}
   \newcommand{\neutralline}{& & & & &}
   \newcommand{\footer}{\centering\rule{7cm}{\cmidrulewidth} \raisebox{-0.5ex}{pyyear} \rule{7cm}{\cmidrulewidth}}
   \newcommand{\printmonthleft}{{\LARGE \textbf{pymonthleft}}}
   \newcommand{\printmonthright}{{\LARGE \textbf{pymonthright}}}
   %
   \advance\stoptime1
   \begin{document}
   \thispagestyle{empty}
   \mbox{}
   \clearpage
   '''

table = r'''
   %% Weeknumber
   \week=pyweek
   \renewcommand{\printmonthleft}{{\LARGE \textbf{pymonthleft}}}
   \renewcommand{\printmonthright}{{\LARGE \textbf{pymonthright}}}
    %% Dates
   \datemonday=pymond
   \datetuesday=pytue
   \datewednesday=pywed
   \datethursday=pythur
   \datefriday=pyfr
   \datesaturday=pysat
   \datesunday=pysun
   %
   %
   %%%%%%%%%% TABLE CONTENT LEFT SIDE %%%%%%%%%%
   %
   \long\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}
   %
   \def\tabledataleft{} \counter=\the\starttime
   \loop
      \edef\tabline{\the\counter &  & \the\counter & & \the\counter & }
      \expandafter\addto\expandafter\tabledataleft\expandafter{\neutralline \\\lend{\mrulew}}
      \expandafter\addto\expandafter\tabledataleft\expandafter{\tabline \\\lend{\trulew}}
      \advance \counter 1
      \ifnum \counter<\the\stoptime
   \repeat
   %
   %%%%%%%%%% TABLE CONTENT RIGHT SIDE %%%%%%%%%%
   %
   \def\tabledatarightupper{} \counter=\the\starttime
   \loop
      \edef\tabline{\the\counter &  & \the\counter & & & }
      \expandafter\addto\expandafter\tabledatarightupper\expandafter{\neutralline \\\lend{\mrulew}}
      \expandafter\addto\expandafter\tabledatarightupper\expandafter{\tabline \\\lend{\trulew}}
      \advance \counter 1
      \ifnum \counter<\the\sundaybegin
   \repeat
   %
   \advance\sundaybegin1
   \def\tabledatarightinter{} \counter=\the\sundaybegin
   \newcount\sundaystop
   \sundaystop=\the\sundaybegin
   \advance\sundaystop1
   \loop
      \edef\tabline{\the\counter &  & \the\counter & & & }
      \expandafter\addto\expandafter\tabledatarightinter\expandafter{\neutralline \\\lsun{\mrulew}}
      \expandafter\addto\expandafter\tabledatarightinter\expandafter{\tabline \\\lsun{\trulew}}
      \advance \counter 1
      \ifnum \counter<\the\sundaystop
   \repeat
   \advance\sundaybegin-1
   \advance\sundaystop1
   %
   \def\tabledatarightlower{} \counter=\the\sundaystop
   \loop
      \edef\tabline{\the\counter &  & \the\counter & & & }
      \expandafter\addto\expandafter\tabledatarightlower\expandafter{\neutralline \\\lend{\mrulew}}
      \expandafter\addto\expandafter\tabledatarightlower\expandafter{\tabline \\\lend{\trulew}}
      \advance \counter 1
      \ifnum \counter<\the\stoptime
   \repeat
   \advance\sundaystop-1
   %
   \pagestyle{empty}
   \enlargethispage{1cm}
   %
   %%%%%%%%%% LEFT TABLE %%%%%%%%%%
   %
   \noindent
   \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lXlXlX}
      \multicolumn{6}{l}{\printmonthleft \hfill {label_week} \the\week}\\[.2em]\midrule[\rulew]
      \addlinespace[.5em]
      \multicolumn{2}{l}{\printday{\the\datemonday}{label_monday}}     &%
      \multicolumn{2}{l}{\printday{\the\datetuesday}{label_tuesday}}   &%
      \multicolumn{2}{l}{\printday{\the\datewednesday}{label_wednesday}}\\[2cm]
       & & & & & \\\lendt
      \tabledataleft
       & & & & & \\\lendt
   \end{tabularx}
   %
   \vfill
   \footer
   %
   \clearpage
   \enlargethispage{1cm}
   %
   %%%%%%%%%% RIGHT TABLE %%%%%%%%%%
   %
   \noindent
   \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lXlXlX}
      \multicolumn{6}{l}{Week \the\week \hfill \printmonthright}\\[.2em]\midrule[\rulew]
      \addlinespace[.5em]
      \multicolumn{2}{l}{\printday{\the\datethursday}{label_thursday}}  &%
      \multicolumn{2}{l}{\printday{\the\datefriday}{label_friday}}     &%
      \multicolumn{2}{l}{\printday{\the\datesaturday}{label_saturday}}  \\[2cm]
      & & & & & \\\lendt
      \tabledatarightupper
      & & & & & \\\lsunt{\mrulew}
      \addlinespace[-.15em]
      \the\sundaybegin & & \the\sundaybegin & & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\multirow{4}{*}[1.5em]{\printday{\the\datesunday}{label_sunday}}}\\\lsun{\trulew}
      \tabledatarightinter
      & & & & & \\\lsun{\mrulew}
      \the\sundaystop & & \the\sundaystop & & & \\\lsunt{\trulew}
      \tabledatarightlower
      & & & & & \\\lendt
   \end{tabularx}
   %
   \vfill
   \footer
   \clearpage'''

for key in labels:
    table = table.replace(key, labels[key])

foot = r'''\end{document}'''

head = head.replace("pyyear",         str(year)      )
head = head.replace("pystarttime",     starttime      )
head = head.replace("pystoptime",      stoptime      )
head = head.replace("pysundaybegin",   sundaybegin    )
head = head.replace("pyextrarowheight", extrarowheight  )
head = head.replace("pyrulewidth",     thickrulewidth  )
head = head.replace("pymidrulewidth",   midrulewidth   )
head = head.replace("pythinrulewidth", thinrulewidth   )

print(head)

week_label = 1

if mondays[0][0] != 1:
   week_label += 1

currentmonth = 0
for week in range(Nweeks):

   table_temp = table
   trigger = 0

   for weekday in range(7):

      date = mondays[week][0] + weekday

      # If it's monday 1 st, increase currentmonth unless it's January 1 st.
      if date == 1 and not (mondays[0][0] == 1 and currentmonth == 0):
         currentmonth += 1
         trigger = 1

      # If next month
      if date > mondays[week][1]:

         date = date - mondays[week][1]

         if trigger == 0:
            currentmonth += 1
            trigger = 1

         # Print right page
         if weekday > 2:
            table_temp = table_temp.replace('pymonthright', months[currentmonth])

         # Print left page
         else:
            table_temp = table_temp.replace('pymonthleft', months[currentmonth])

      else:

         # Print left page
         if weekday == 2:
            table_temp = table_temp.replace('pymonthleft', months[currentmonth])

         # Print right page
         elif weekday == 6:
            table_temp = table_temp.replace('pymonthright', months[currentmonth])

      table_temp = table_temp.replace(days[weekday], str(date))

   table_temp = table_temp.replace("pyweek", str(week_label))
   print(table_temp)
   week_label += 1

print(foot)
```

It prints the LaTeX-source to stdout so use it via:

```
python script.py > filename.tex && pdflatex filename.tex
```

Furthermore I added the parameter (compare below):

- `thickrulewidth`
- `midrulewidth`
- `thinrulewidth`

All labels are now easily changeable within the CUSTOMIZATIONS block.

### [image: final]

**EDIT 2**

As of 2018, the code broke. Going into the details again, I noticed what an wretched piece of code I uploaded. I'm sorry for that and rewrote most of it now.

The updated code above is now `python3` conform, commented, readable, more flexible in terms of customization and -- most important -- works for the coming years as well. Happy new year!

---

**EDIT 3**

Another some years have passed. [Here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Q7eM2r-RH8bNP1xXqYw84zXZMLazX9bN) are readily compiled years 2021-2029.

Comment: Amazing: You asked a question and provided the solution to it at the same minute! ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Amazing?  yes.  But now all it takes is $19.95 worth of printer ink!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer You have 53 weeks, with one week per A4 side. Double-side printing results in 27 sheets of A4 paper with less ink consumption than two full pages of text. Ink and paper together will cost you not more than a few cents.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Taking my usual expenditures for paper and toner, I roughly calculated a total of **65** complete calender inlays by spending $ 19.95. :-)
Btw.: I'm sorry for mistaking the nick in the post above.

Comment: @smoneck: I just wondered ;-)

Comment: Can somebody help me to explain how I should paste this solution in something like overleaf. In particulaly: where do I put the python code?

Comment: @ArneTimperman The Python code can run on any machine with Python installed, not in Overleaf itself. Alternatively, I just tested it successfully from a [JupyterLab instance](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-demo/master?urlpath=lab/tree/demo).
The code it produces can be copy pasted into Overleaf then.
I also edited the answer above to replace the outdated PDFs 2018-2020 with 2021-2029. 

Comment: @Suuuehgi I just compiled my first Python code without knowing what I'm doing, but it worked!!! Thanks!!!!